# platform agnostic USER in npm script

Tags: npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I am looking for a way to pass the `os` username in an npm script. However, I need the script to be able to run platform agnostic. Is there anyway I can do this?

On **unix** I can do;

```json
{
 "scripts":{
    "dosomething" : "somethirdpartypackage -someparamater $USER"
  }
}
```

`npm run dosomething`

and on **windows**

```json
{
 "scripts":{
    "dosomething" : "somethirdpartypackage -someparamater %USERNAME%"
  }
}
```

`npm run dosomething`

But I need some way to do it platform agnostic.

Also ideally I would like to lowercase the username before passing it as an argument to `somethirdpartypackage`

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** npm does not provide a built-in feature to achieve this.

The [cross-var](https://github.com/elijahmanor/cross-var) package provides a single syntax to address the differences regarding how variables are referenced across platforms. Those differences being:

- A dollar prefix `$` is required on *[*nix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like)* operating systems *(Linux, macOS, etc)*.
- Encasing the variable name in percent signs `%...%` is required on Windows.

However, `cross-var` doesn't address the different environment variable names required across operating systems, i.e.

- `USER` is required on **nix*.
- `USERNAME` is required on Windows.

Given your custom requirement and the conditional logic required to do this in a cross-platform compatible way you'll need to utilize node.js.

---

### Solution A:

Consider utilizing a node.js script such as `dosomething.js` shown below:

1. Firstly save `dosomething.js` in the root of your project directory, i.e. save it to the same folder where `package.json` resides.

   ```
   project
   ├── dosomething.js   <---
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   ├── package.json
   └── ...
   ```

   **dosomething.js**

   ```js
   var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

   var user = process.platform === 'win32'
       ? process.env.USERNAME
       : process.env.USER;

   var cmd = 'somethirdpartypackage -someparamater "' + user.toLowerCase() + '"';

   execSync(cmd, { stdio: [0, 1, 2]});
   ```

   **Note:** Of course you'll need to redefine the contrived `somethirdpartypackage -someparamater` part as necessary.
2. Then in `package.json` define your npm script called `dosomething` as follows:

   **package.json** *(excerpt)*

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "dosomething": "node dosomething.js"
   },
   ```

**Explanation:**

The following explains what `dosomething.js` does:

1. Firstly we require the builtin [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) method from the `child_process` module.
2. Using the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) we ascertain whether the [`process.platform`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform) value is `win32`.

   - If the platform is `win32` we assign the value of the `USERNAME` environment variable (using [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) to obtain it) to the `user` variable.
   - Similarly, if the platform is *NOT* `win32` we assume it to be **nix* and assign the value of the `USER` environment variable to the `user` variable.
3. We then assign the command that we want to execute to the `cmd` variable.

   - Note the `user.toLowerCase()` part utilizes the [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method to lowercase the username.
4. Finally via `execSync()` we pass in the command that we want to execute.

   - The [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio) part configures the pipes for stdin, stdout, stderr in the child process.

**Note:**

If you wanted to remove any space characters from the username too, you could change the line #7 in `dosomething.js` to the following:

```js
var cmd = 'somethirdpartypackage -someparamater "' + user.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase() + '"';
```

This additionally utilizes the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method (with an single space delimiter) to split the string to an array. Then subsequently [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)'s the array back to a string.

---

### Solution B:

If you wanted to avoid using a separate node.js script file, i.e. `dosomething.js`. Then in your npm script utilize the node.js command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) to evaluate the inline JavaScript instead.

For instance;

**package.json** *(excerpt)*

```js
"scripts": {
  "dosomething": "node -e \"var user = process.platform === 'win32' ? process.env.USERNAME : process.env.USER; require('child_process').execSync('somethirdpartypackage -someparamater \\\"' + user.toLowerCase() + '\\\"', { stdio: [0, 1, 2]});\""
}
```

This is essentially the same code as per `dosomething.js`, albeit slightly refactored.

If you wanted to remove any spaces in the username, then define your npm script as follows:

```js
"scripts": {
  "dosomething": "node -e \"var user = process.platform === 'win32' ? process.env.USERNAME : process.env.USER; require('child_process').execSync('somethirdpartypackage -someparamater \\\"' + user.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase() + '\\\"', { stdio: [0, 1, 2]});\""
}
```

**Note**: Again, of course you'll need to redefine the contrived `somethirdpartypackage -someparamater` part as necessary.

Btw. the space character after the `-someparamater` part shown in all examples throughout this answer is intentional - ensure you keep it.